# How to set Chrome app's max width narrower than the width of minimize, maximize, close -buttons?

Tags: javascript, css, windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have made a simple chrome app which should only need to be 50px wide for my purposes.
But currently I have not figured out how to make window really narrower than about 140px which the window will come.

Even if I set the `width` and `maxWidth` properties to 50px. And when window is narrow as possible, it contains the minimize, maximize and close button. So maybe they are because Windows need them to be?
I tried to make it borderless (/frameless), but same problem with the width still occurs.

Is it possible to remove the minimize and maximize buttons? Or is it even possible to make the chrome app so narrow?

*Currently have only tested this on Windows 7*

Comment: Try [disabling the native frame](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/frameless-window).

Comment: I already look that link and that's what I mean with borderless. Didn't help.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes, my frameless/borderless window did not have any buttons. But they seemed to take up the same space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already tried frameless, there's likely nothing you can do. I tested it on Windows 10, same result.

Seems like for frameless windows Chrome creates a normal window (constrained in size by displaying those controls in Windows) and just overrides how it's painted.

It seems to be a [reported bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224860) with not much activity. With Chrome Apps being deprecated on Windows, I don't see this getting fixed.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for finding that. I have to live with that problem then.